# String index out of range - Python Logic Based error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def double_chars(word):
    for j in range(len(word)):
        if word[j] == word[j:j+1]:
            chars_count = chars_count + 1
    return chars_count

test_word = "Hello..world!"
print(double_chars(test_word))


Error: if word[j] == word[j+1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I keep getting string index out of range on this function. I have tried different ways of indexing and slicing.

I am trying to return the count of character in a string that has double characters for example: `bell--rung --> "ll" = 1`, and "--" = 1. hence count of 2.

Am I doing something wrong in the code?

Comment: How about using `range(len(word) - 1)`? Probably your error arises when `j` reaches the last character (i.e., `j = len(word) - 1)`) in which case `j+1` is out of range. This might introduce (or not) another edge case when you provide an empty `word`. Deal with that separately if needed.

Comment: Why you post shows `word[j:j+1]` and the error `word[j+1]`

Comment: @azro I was trying to recreate the error… my bad

Comment: @j1-lee thanks a lot, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the range generates from `0` (inclusive) to the string's length (exclusive) which is ok for indexing, as string are 0-based indexed, but you don't only access current index, also the next one, so when reaching the last value of `j`, the `[j+1]` is one too far

```
def double_chars(word):
    chars_count = 0
    for j in range(len(word) - 1):
        if word[j] == word[j + 1]:
            chars_count += 1
    return chars_count
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `x[j]` | H | e | l | l | o | . | . | w | o | r | l | d |
| `x[j+1]` | e | l | l | o | . | . | w | o | r | l | d | ! |

---

One-liner proposal, and another with `zip`

```
def double_chars(word):
    return sum(1 for j in range(len(word) - 1) if word[j] == word[j + 1])

def double_chars(word):
    return sum(1 for ch_curr, ch_next in zip(word, word[1:]) if ch_curr == ch_next)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Your answer solves the problem and also helps me understand better. Thanks!